# Firestore PERMISSION_DENIED error in all cases of rules

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to register a new user. The user data consists of a password and a password hint. I want to save the hint in the Firestore document, but any rule I write in the Firestore gives an error:

> W/Firestore: (24.4.5) [WriteStream]: (4e2f22c) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

This is my code

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestore db1 = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("password_hint", hint);
            if (user != null) {
                db1.collection("users").document(user.getUid())
                        .set(userMap)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivityPass.this, BiometricActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error adding user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "User is not logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my Firestore rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    // Only authenticated users can access the 'users' collection
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

No matter what rule i set, the error will appear in any case.

Comment: Where is this error message coming from? As inside onFailure I only see "Error adding user".

Comment: Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help. If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).